# Select data based on weekday and weekend pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, python-datetime

I have a df like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

datetime = [('2019-09-15 00:15:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 00:30:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 00:45:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 01:00:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 01:15:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 01:30:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 01:45:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 02:00:00.000000000'),
            ('2019-09-15 02:15:00.000000000')]
p =[494.76,486.36,484.68,500.64,482.16,483.84,483.0,478.8,493.08,474.6]
q = [47.88,33.6,41.16,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(datetime, p, q), columns=['datetime','p','q'])
df['week'] (df['datetime'].astype('datetime64[ns]') + pd.Timedelta(seconds=-15*60)).dt.day_name()
```

And now that I have defined the days of the week where each day starts at `00:15:00` and ends at the `00:00:00` after 96 points. I want to separate them into two other df's. In one only the weekdays and in the other only the weekends. I've tried:

```
df_week = df[~df['datetime'].dt.day_name().isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])]
df_weekend = df[df['datetime'].dt.day_name().isin(['Saturday','Sunday'])]
```

Although the code runs without errors, I'm having an output that includes one data for "Saturday" at the df_week. Like this:

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this I use the `.loc` function:

```
monday = df.loc[(df['week'] == 'Monday')]
tuesday = df.loc[(df['week'] == 'Tuesday')]
df_w = pd.concat([monday,tuesday])
```

Not the fastest solution, but it worked

Answer (score 2):

I am new-ish to Pandas but I think the following works:

```
df1 = df[df['week'].isin(['Sunday', 'Saturday'])]

df2 = df[~df['week'].isin(['Sunday', 'Saturday'])]
```

Hopefully someone more capable can also help to verify

Comment: Thanks, but doing like this I'm not getting all the datas from the days.